# Reprocess one measure group and browse cube in SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

A user was browsing our sales cube using PowerBi and noticed that measure group Fact Finance was incorrect.

The issue was an incorrect relationship. I added the relationship between FactFinance and DimAccount. Since processing the whole cube takes over an hour, I prefer processing this measure group, check the values in the SSDT browser, and publish the cube if everything's good.

How can I process just one Measure group so that I can browse the cube (ie. this measure) in SSDT and make sure everything's correct?

The reason I ask is that the SSDT browser connects to the actual cube, so I'm not sure how I can just process and deploy one measure group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to the Cube and refresh (technically it's called "Processing"), with a variety of tools.  The most common for a manual re-processing is SQL Server Management Studio.  See [Tools and Approaches for Processing (Analysis Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/tools-and-approaches-for-processing-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions)

Comment: The issue is that reprocessing the entire cube takes an hour. I want to reprocess one measure group and somehow check if the measure group is correct.

Comment: You can Process one Measure Group, or just one partition of a Measure group if you want.  But if you didn't partition your Measure Group it still might take a long time to reprocess.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/processing-analysis-services-objects?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_procmeasure